# How can I use Terminal/defaults to set "Click wallpaper to reveal desktop" to "Only in Stage Manager"

Tags: macos, terminal, defaults, sonoma

Basically the title.  How can I set the `Click wallpaper to reveal desktop` setting in macOS Sonoma to `Only in Stage Manager` using Terminal?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
defaults write com.apple.WindowManager EnableStandardClickToShowDesktop -bool false
```

...will limit the setting to "Only in Stage Manager".

You may have to kill WindowManager for it to take effect straight away.

```
killall WindowManager
```